# Unable to Remove Class for Span Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying do remove class `"bg-color-disable"` for `#filenameRPT` but nothing I tried work. I have used `$("#parentRPT > span#filenameRPT").removeClass("bg-color-disable");` and `$("#filenameRPT").removeClass("bg-color-disable");` but no lucks. Any idea?

```
<div class="two-row mb-3">
  <div id="parentRPT" class="input-group bg-color-disable">
    <span class="input-group-addon gi data-gi-size gi-file-plus"></span>
    <span id="filenameRPT" class="bg-color-disable">
      Upload REPORT
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right text-primary ml-1 mr-1"></span>
      <a name="rpt" href="#">No File Exists</a
      <input class="hidden" name="delete_RPT" value="not_deleted" type="text"/>
    </span>
    <span id="deleteRPT" class="fa fa-times text-danger hidden" title="Delete"></span>
    <label class="input-group-addon has-float-label" for="file-uploadRPT">
      Browse
      <input id="file-uploadRPT" name="FileToUploadRPT" type="file" accept="application/pdf">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Crazy thing is I was able to remove "bg-color-disable" for `#parentRPT` using `$("#parentRPT").removeClass("bg-color-disable");` but using `$("#filenameRPT").removeClass("bg-color-disable");` didn't work for element `#filenameRPT`. Why?

Comment: It does work to remove the class. It just doesn't affect what you see: that span will inherit styles from it's parent elements, in this case the div.

Comment: They both work fine here https://jsfiddle.net/shnmaoe0/

Comment: I wonder if this is more to do with the browser trying to fix syntax errors in your HTML. Where is the `span#filenameRPT` closing tag?

Comment: @Jared Smith True, but if the code worked then I should be able to see the class removed when I inspect the element but it didn't.

Comment: @fubar The span closing tag was included.

Comment: @ninjachuku - My mistake. It wasn't clear with the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is with improper closing of anchor tag.
Removing class is straight forward.

```js
window.onload = removeClass()

function removeClass() {
   console.log('before removal',document.getElementById('filenameRPT').classList);
   document.getElementById('filenameRPT').classList.remove('bg-color-disable')
   console.log('after removal',document.getElementById('filenameRPT').classList);
}
```

```html
<div class="two-row mb-3">
  <div id="parentRPT" class="input-group bg-color-disable">
    <span class="input-group-addon gi data-gi-size gi-file-plus"></span>
    <span id="filenameRPT" class="bg-color-disable">
      Upload REPORT
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right text-primary ml-1 mr-1"></span>
      <a name="rpt" href="#">No File Exists</a>
      <input class="hidden" name="delete_RPT" value="not_deleted" type="text"/>
    </span>
    <span id="deleteRPT" class="fa fa-times text-danger hidden" title="Delete"></span>
    <label class="input-group-addon has-float-label" for="file-uploadRPT">
      Browse
      <input id="file-uploadRPT" name="FileToUploadRPT" type="file" accept="application/pdf">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```